# How does macro expansion work in below code?

Tags: c

In the code below, according to me, the output should be `11 6 10`, but it gives `12 6 11`. The value of `k=x` as returned by the ternary operator since `x>y` where `x=10` and `y=6`, so `i=11`, `j=6` and `k=10`, so why is there a mismatch in the output produced?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(x,y)(x)>(y)?(x):(y)

int main()
{
    int i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k=MAX(i++,++j);
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Badly, even though the behaviour is fully defined.

Comment: Compare to `k = (i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j)` which is what the macro expands to.

Comment: never write code like this unless you want to take part in The International Obfuscated C Code Contest

Comment: @Oliver: Good duplicate, even down to the missing outer parentheses, the same three variables, and the same initial values for `i` and `j`.

Comment: Is your spacebar broken? Get a new keyboard!

Answer (score 2):

The expansion is equivalent to:

```
k = (i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j);
```

Both `i` and `j` are incremented as the condition is evaluated (so `i` becomes `11` and `j` becomes `6`.  Since the condition checks the original value of `i` and the incremented value of `j` and `10 > 6`, the `i++` after the `?` is evaluated, so `k` is assigned `11` and `i` is incremented to 12.

Hence the output is, as it should be:

```
12 6 11
```

There is no undefined behaviour here.  There's a full sequence point after the condition is evaluated.

Note, too, that for full safety, the macro should have an extra set of parentheses around the expansion:

```
#define MAX(x,y)  ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

Otherwise, you get odd-ball effects from:

```
int l = 7 * MAX(k, i) + 3;
```

It works; it just doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `(i++) > (++j)` is this guaranteed that both `i` and `j` are incremented after the comparison? (and before the `?`)

Comment: Yes; both `i` and `j` are incremented when the comparison is complete and before either of the terms after the question mark is evaluated.

Comment: so in this particular case, it's the same as writing `(++i) > (++j) ? (++i) : (++j);` ?

Comment: No; because in your rewrite, the value assigned to `k` would be 12, not 11, because of the preincrement of `i` after the `?`. Also, with other values for `i` and `j` (such as `i = 6` and `j = 5`), the comparisons `(i++) > (++j)` and `(++i) > (++j)` would evaluate differently.

Comment: ok thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 1):

The output works as expected. You'll need to understand macros are expanded, and do not work like functions where the input parameters are copied.

The definition of MAX in the above code is

```
#define MAX(x, y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
```

So

```
k = MAX(i++, ++j)
```

expands to

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j)
```

The variable i gets incremented twice when i=10 and j=5. The variable j gets incremented only once.

So eventually i=12 and j=6, and k=11 because the second operand in the ternary operator is a post-increment.

If you are using gcc, running *cpp* instead of *gcc* on the .c file would expand the macro nicely for you.

Apart from Jonathan Leffler's comment on using more parentheses in the macro for safety, you can consider using inline functions that could save you from these unintended results. Inline functions have the benefits of being typed, passing-by-value, and code expansion.

```
inline int max(int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }
```

See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#Comparison_with_macros) for more details.